# Django; redirect doesn't work as expected when using ajax

Tags: python, django

I'm creating delete function using ajax. redirect doesn't work as expected.

`js`

```
function deleteEntry(entry) {

    var id = $entry.data('id')
    $.ajax({
        url:'/blog/delete/' + id,
        method: 'DELETE',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrf_token)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

`views.py`

```
def delete_entry(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, id=pk)
        entry.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('blog:list_entry'))
```

command line is like this when doing the function

```
[13/Sep/2018 16:06:02] "DELETE /blog/delete/14 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Sep/2018 16:06:02] "DELETE /blog/list HTTP/1.1" 200 9878
[13/Sep/2018 16:06:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10605
```

I want to make the page redirect to `blog/list` but the page redirects to `/`.
I don't want to create template for this view and also I'm thinking of doing something like confirm window so I want to call the function using js.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. The *whole point* of using Ajax is that it bypasses the browser's normal navigation. Why are you using Ajax at all if you want the browser to redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/blog/delete/' + id,
    method: 'DELETE',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrf_token)
    },
    success: function () {
       window.location.href = {% url 'the_get_url_you_wanted_to_redirect_to' %}
    }
})
```

Do note this is a duplicate question asked quite a few times here in stackoverflow, so its best to search first before posting a new question. :) Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it works. I did try to do `location.href = url` when I searched but it didn't work.. But your answer did work. I appreciate.

Comment: This way doesn't work suddenly... The error says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %`

Answer (score 0):

One thing that seems to work well that isn't mentioned..

Ajax Call Success:

```
 success: function (response) {
     
     if("redirect" in response){

         window.location.href = response["redirect"];

    }
 }
```

Instead of using HttpResponseRedirect you use this in your view

```
return JsonResponse({"redirect":'/customer/buyer'}, status=200)
```